# how to add city dropdown on checkout page instead of typing the city(M2)

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, customer-attribute

I need to get rid of this company text field and Country drop down since the store serves locally.

Important :
How I can overide the city (text area) to a drop down with my own custom city list.?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Extension1: you can install [this](https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown) free extension for display city

visit [this](https://packagist.org/packages/php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown) link for how to install `composer require php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown`

For more details how to set up check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugZXjsNKM0w&index=6&list=PL98CDCbI3TNslCicN4cJyR4_hBXR1clhW) link

Extension2: https://github.com/EaDesgin/Magento2-City-Dropdown

Comment: There isnt any code in this github repo?!?

Comment: please run composer require php-cuong/magento2-city-dropdown command from magento root, you will get extension in vendor

Answer (score 1):

In your block
\Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory

```
public function getCountries()
{
    $collection = $this->countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore()->toOptionArray(false);
        return $collection;

}
```

In your template file

```
<div class="field name required">
                <label class="label" for="customer_country"><span>Country</span></label>
                <div class="control">
                <?php
                    $countryList=$block->getCountries();
                    ?>
                    <div class="field country">

                        <select class="required-entry" id="country" name="country"> 
                            <option value="">Please Select</option>        
                             <?php foreach ($countryList as $key => $country) {?>
                             <option value="<?php echo $country['value']; ?>"><?php echo $country['label']; ?></option>
                             <?php } ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                </div>
</div>
```